# SFML multi-touch events and finger indexes

Tags: mobile, sfml, multi-touch

I've been wondering how to make multi-touch feature using SFML. Official documentation says that touches are identified by "finger" index. But but they don't work as they supposed to in my case. For example function Touch::isDown(finger index) sees the parameter as number of touches, not as index of finger. I tried creating TouchEvent and setting .finger attribute but it didn't work either.
There are no any tutorials or examples of SFML multi-touch in the internet. Please explain me how to achieve that or provide a little example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some misunderstanding, that's exactly how it's supposed to work.

All fingers are same to a touchscreen. A touchscreen can only detect touches, it cannot detect whether you used index finger or middle finger to touch.

**Explanation :-**

Now when multiple fingers are touched simuntaneously, sfml assigns them a index number in the order they were touched.

If you touch one finger, it will get index 0. Then you touch 2 more fingers, they get index 1 and 2.

Even if you lift one finger, indexes of other fingers are preserved as long as atleast one finger is touched. Indexes will reset when no finger is touched.

**Code Example :-**

You can check if second finger (index 1) is touched by using `sf::Touch::isDown(1)` and then get touch co-ordinates with

```cpp
if (sf::Touch::isDown(1))
{
    sf::Vector2 touch_pos = sf::Touch::getPosition(1);
    
    std::cout << "x-pos :" << touch_pos.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y-pos :" << touch_pos.y << std::endl;
}
```